# UIButton animation on pressing

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

How can we animate UIButton to reach the effect that when pressing the button, it will show slow pressing down effect and feel like you are pressing on a soft cushion. Same when moving fingers away. Is there a way to do that programmingly or using some images?

Comment: This is just a word of advice and it doesn't answer your question, but I'd suggest that you only animate the touch up event. If you animate the touch down, it does not feel right; it almost feels laggy and destroys the illusion that you're actually touching somewhat realistic content. I'd suggest you make the touch up instantaneous, and the touch out a somewhat fast fade, and it will feel much better. Sorry for the little rant here, just trying to help.

Comment: that helps! if you can provide a piece of sample code doing the fading etc, that'll be awesome